# S3 event based Trigger for multiple files in same folder

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to write an S3 event-based trigger for a bucket. I'm thinking of the event being triggered once when an individual dataset is dropped.

However, the problem is that there are over 140 datasets that are dropped in the S3 bucket at different times and dates (daily, weekly, bi-weekly and monthly). Since this bucket will receive multiple dataset/files every day, is there a way to trigger a different Lambda function for each filename?

The format of the filename is `file_name_date.parquet` (`file_name_20240322.parquet`). The filename will always be the same but the date will always be different.

Comment: What can be used to identify that all files have been uploaded, so that processing can begin?

Comment: When you say "trigger a different Lambda function for each filename", are you saying that you _always_ want to trigger a Lambda function for _every_ object uploaded, but the Lambda function to call will depend upon the first part of the object's name?

Comment: That is correct. Every time a file is uploaded, Lambda function to call should depend upon the first part of the object's name, since all these files should be processed differently, a different lambda function should be called depending on the file's name

Comment: You can specify a `Prefix` when defining the Event. This should let you trigger a different Lambda function based on the filename.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are saying:

- Many files are **uploaded** to an Amazon S3 bucket
- Once "all" files are uploaded, you wish to **trigger an AWS Lambda function**
- However, the Lambda function gets triggered for *every* object that is created

The problem here is **knowing when "all" files are uploaded**.

A good way to handle this is to **add an operation to the system that is uploading the files** so that, once all files are uploaded, it uploads an extra file either with a special filename or, preferably, in a different directory. This 'extra file' could then be used to trigger your next process.

- For a file with a '**special filename**', you would actually trigger the Lambda function on every object creation, but the Lambda function would check the filename as the first operation. If it is *not* the 'special filename', then it exits immediately (at very little cost).
- For a **file created in a different directory**, you would simply configure the S3 Event to only trigger on that different directory.

Comment: That is what i thought as well. I was wondering if there was a way to only trigger a specific lambda per file name, however, that does not seem like the case.

Comment: You can specify a Prefix and a Suffix. So, you could probably configure it to only react on a specific filename if you want one particular file to trigger the Lambda function.